# showing this error ValueError: shapes (1,400) and (10000,10) not aligned: 400 (dim 1) != 10000 (dim 0)

Tags: machine-learning, data, data-science-model

I am trying to run a network and get this error .I am a noob,can someone help me.

```
import numpy as np, sys
np.random.seed(1)

from keras.datasets import mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test,y_test)=mnist.load_data()

images,labels=(x_train[0:1000].reshape(1000,28*28)/255,
               y_train[0:1000])

one_hot_labels =np.zeros((len(labels),10))
for i,l in enumerate(labels):
    one_hot_labels[i][l]=1
labels=one_hot_labels

test_images=x_test.reshape(len(x_test),28*28)/255
test_labels =np.zeros((len(y_test),10))
for i,l in enumerate(y_test):
    test_labels[i][l]=1

def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)

def tanh2deriv(output):
    return 1 -(output**2)

def softmax(x):
    temp=np.exp(x)
    return temp /np.sum(temp, axis=1, keepdims=True)

alpha, iterations=(2,300)
pixels_per_image, num_labels =(784,10)
batch_size=128

input_rows=28
input_cols=28

kernel_rows=3
kernel_cols=3

num_kernels=16

hidden_size=((input_rows-kernel_rows)*
            (input_cols-kernel_cols))*num_kernels

kernels=0.02*np.random.random((kernel_rows*kernel_cols,
                       num_kernels))-0.01


weights_1_2=0.2*np.random.random((hidden_size,num_labels))-0.01

def get_image_section(layer,row_from, row_to, col_from, col_to):
    section=layer[:,row_from:row_to,col_from:col_to]
    return section.reshape(-1,1,row_to-row_from, col_to-col_from)

for j in range(iterations):
    correct_cnt=0
    for i in range(int(len(images)/batch_size)):
        batch_start, batch_end=((i*batch_size),((i+1)*batch_size))
        layer_0=images[batch_start:batch_end]
        layer_0=layer_0.reshape(layer_0.shape[0],28,28)
        layer_0.shape
        
        sects=list()
        for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows):
            for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols):
                sect=get_image_section(layer_0,
                                      row_start,
                                      row_start+kernel_rows,
                                      col_start,
                                      col_start+kernel_cols)
                sects.append(sect)
        expanded_input=np.concatenate(sects,axis=1)
        es= expanded_input.shape
        flattened_input=expanded_input.reshape(es[0]*es[1],-1)
        
        kernel_output=flattened_input.dot(kernels)
        layer_1=tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0],-1))
        dropout_mask=np.random.randint(2,size=layer_1.shape)
        layer_1 *=dropout_mask*2
        layer_2=softmax(np.dot(layer_1,weights_1_2))
        
        for k in range(batch_size):
            labelset=labels[batch_start+k:batch_start+k+1]
            _inc=int(np.argmax(layer_2[k:k+1])==
                    np.argmax(labelset))
            correct_cnt += _inc
        
        layer_2_delta=(labels[batch_start:batch_end]-layer_2)\
                        / (batch_size * layer_2.shape[0])
        layer_1_delta=layer_2_delta.dot(weights_1_2.T)*\
                        tanh2deriv(layer_1)
        layer_1_delta *=dropout_mask
        weights_1_2 += alpha*layer_1.T.dot(layer_2_delta)
        l1d_reshape=layer_1_delta.reshape(kernel_output.shape)
        k_update = flattened_input.T.dot(l1d_reshape)
        kernels -= alpha*k_update#二维图像输出
        
    test_correct_cnt=0
    
    for i in range(len(test_images)):
        
        layer_0=test_images[i:i+1]
        layer_0=layer_0.reshape(layer_0.shape[0],28,28)
        layer_0.shape
        
        sects=list()
        
    for row_start in range(layer_0.shape[1]-kernel_rows):
        for col_start in range(layer_0.shape[2]-kernel_cols):
            sect=get_image_section(layer_0,
                                  row_start,
                                  row_start+kernel_rows,
                                  col_start,
                                  col_start+kernel_cols)
            sects.append(sect)
        expanded_input=np.concatenate(sects,axis=1)
        es=expanded_input.shape
        flattened_input=expanded_input.reshape(es[0]*es[1],-1)
        
        kernel_output=flattened_input.dot(kernels)
        layer_1=tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0],-1))
        layer_2 =  np.dot(layer_1,weights_1_2)
        test_correct_cnt += int(np.argmax(layer_2)==
                                np.argmax(test_labels[i:i+1]))
    if(j % 1 == 0):
        sys.stdout.write("\n"+\
         "I:"+str(j)+ \
         "Test-Acc:"+str(test_correct_cnt/float(len(test_images)))+\
         "Train-Acc:"+str(correct_cnt/float(len(images))))
```

however i get this error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-6c33a1c4b65c> in <module>
    121         kernel_output=flattened_input.dot(kernels)
    122         layer_1=tanh(kernel_output.reshape(es[0],-1))
--> 123         layer_2 =  np.dot(layer_1,weights_1_2)
    124         test_correct_cnt += int(np.argmax(layer_2)==
    125                                 np.argmax(test_labels[i:i+1]))

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: shapes (1,400) and (10000,10) not aligned: 400 (dim 1) != 10000 (dim 0)
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: You are trying to matrix multiply the `layer_1` and `weights_1_2` matrices which is returning an error since the second dimension of the first matrix and the first dimension of the second matrix need to be of the same size. Make sure that the two matrices have the correct shape, in line with the dimensions of your input and neural network architecture.

Comment: so how should i change the code,sir.I have tried to change the matrix but doesn't work